# Why is my slider stacking images on top of each other rather than showing the slider?

Tags: html, image, slider

I am trying to implement a slider into my webpage. However the images seem to be stacking on top of one another rather than showing the images sliding from one page to the next.
The sliders '<' and '>' arrows are a also stacked and appearing at the bottom of the page.
I have edited this over and over again, and are beginning to loose track of how to edit the slider.

Can anyone guide me as to why the images are not integrating into the slider?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<div align="center">
<p><img src="1_Images/Porshce Emblem.jpg" alt="Porsche Emblem" width="151" height="94" longdesc= "https://www.google.com/search?q=porsche+emblem&amp;safe=off&amp;tbm=isch&amp;imgil=e3SyBtCbC2kTgM%253A%253Bhttps%253A%252F%252Fencrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com%252Fimages%253Fq%253Dtbn%253AANd9GcQN4XhkcCDBk4z-ZnDUyqPlFdU0jZCu4zqA_G9W5nUkfHPVFKaI%253B1600%253B1039%253BsCzj1iXrWOgv-M%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.zeroto60times.com%25252Fblog%25252Flarge-car-logos-2%25252Flarge-porsche-car-logo%25252F&amp;source=iu&amp;usg=__kv3nkjDu2-Zh6vo4K9VKHSpmMLc%3D&amp;sa=X&amp;ei=ISi0U6GRDcKYyAS8nYKgDw&amp;sqi=2&amp;ved=0CB4Q9QEwAA&amp;biw=1280&amp;bih=621#facrc=_&amp;imgdii=_&amp;imgrc=e3SyBtCbC2kTgM%253A%3BsCzj1iXrWOgv-M%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.zeroto60times.com%252Fblog%252Fwp-content%252Fuploads%252F2013%252F02%252Fporsche-cars-logo-emblem.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.zeroto60times.com%252Fblog%252Flarge-car-logos-2%252Flarge-porsche-car-logo%252F%3B1600%3B1039"/></p>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round");
html, body { background: #333 url("http://codepen.io/images/classy_fabric.png"); }

<!--do not edit position-->

.slides {
padding: 0;
width: 800px;
height: 300px;
display: block;
position: relative;  
margin: auto;
left: 0px;
right: 0px; 
top: 0px;    

}
.slides * {

user-select: none;
ms-user-select: none;
moz-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

.slides input { display: none; }

.slide-container { display: inline, block; }
<!--  image properties below-->
.slide { 
top: -12px;
opacity: 0;
width: 800px;
height: 300px;
display: block;
position: relative;
transform: scale(0);

transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
left: -98px;
}

.slide img {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.nav label {
width: 50px;
height: 100%;
display: none;
position: absolute;
opacity: 0;
z-index: 9;
cursor: pointer;

transition: opacity.2s;
color: #FFF;
font-size: 100pt;
text-align: center;
line-height: 300px;
font-family: "Varela Round", sans-serif;
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(119, 119, 119);
}

.slide:hover + .nav label { opacity: 0.5; }

.nav label:hover { opacity: 1; }

.nav .next { right: 0; }

input:checked + .slide-container  .slide {
opacity: 1;

transform: scale(1);

transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

input:checked + .slide-container .nav label { display: block; }

.nav-dots {
width: 100px;
bottom: -75px;
height: 59px;
display: block;
position: block;
text-align: center;
left: -284px;
}
<!-- arrow stats
.nav-dots .nav-dot {
top: -5px;
width: 100px;
height: 11px;
margin: 0, 4px;
position: fixed;
display: inline-block;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.nav-dots .nav-dot:hover {
cursor: pointer;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);

}

input#img-1:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-1,
input#img-2:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-2,
input#img-3:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-3,
input#img-4:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-4,
input#img-5:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-5,
input#img-6:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-6 {
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);

} 
.slide1 {
top: -10px;
opacity: 0;
width: 600px;
height: 300px;
display: block;
position: absolute;
transform: scale(0);

transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
left: -298px;
}

</style>

<body>
<!-- code for the sliders position on page-->
<ul class="slides">
<input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-1" checked />
<li class="slide-container">
<div class="slide">

<!--Image 1 - first image in slider-->
<img src="1_Images/Porsche Homepage.jpg" /><img src="1_Images/porsche_cayman_s_5-wide[1].jpg" width="110%" class="slide-container" /><img src="1_Images/Porsche Transparent Car.jpg" height="82%" /><img src="1_Images/Porsche 918.jpg" /></div>
<div class="nav">
<label for="img-6" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
<label for="img-2" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
</div>
</li>

<input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-2" />
<li class="slide-container">
<div class="slide">   </div> 
<div class="nav">
<label for="img-1" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
<label for="img-3" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
</div>
</li>

<input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-3" />
<li class="slide-container">
<div class="slide"></div>
<div class="nav">
<label for="img-2" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
<label for="img-4" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
</div>
</li>

<input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-4" />
<li class="slide-container">
<div class="slide"></div>
</li>
<li class="slide-container">
<div class="slide">
<div align="center" class="slide-container"></div>
</div>
<div class="nav">
<label for="img-4" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
<label for="img-6" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
</div>
</li>

<input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-6" />
<li class="slide-container">
<div class="slide-container"></div>
</li>
<li class="slide-container">
<div class="nav">
<label for="img-1" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-1"></label>
<label for="img-2" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-2"></label>
<label for="img-3" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-3"></label>
<label for="img-4" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-4"></label>
<label for="img-5" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-5"></label>
<label for="img-6" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-6"></label>
</div>
</li>
```

Comment: you have 2 head tags and html in the first head tag and you never close either of them, you also don't close your div tag in the first head